# Use of Activator.CreateInstance(...) in ASP.NET MVC Unit Test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2

Today I started adding unit tests to an ASP.NET MVC project we are developing for some time now. I created a new Test project and let VS 2010 generate all the test classes.

After running the resulting tests, all tests are failing. Debugging shows that most tests are failing because of a `TargetInvocationException` (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.) that occurs at the line

```
object context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

...which is used to initialize the DataContext of the application. Why is this exception thrown during test runs, and how can it be prevented?

Comment: That is a very vague Exception. Run it again and check the Inner Exception for more detail...and post it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TargetInvocationException`, when thrown from `Activator.CreateInstance`, usually means the code inside the constructor is throwing an exception.  As Justin mentioned, the inner exception can help you determine what exactly went wrong.

Comment: Had a look at the InnerException property, and it stated "The type initializer for 'DBDataContext' threw an exception.". And indeed, it appeared that this initializer was requesting a connection string via the ConfigurationManager class... but my test project was lacking a app.config file. Problem was fixed by adding this file, and inserting a connection string in it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Entity Framework alongside (or maybe Linq to Sql). Could it be that you need to configure a connection string in your test project (through App.config)?